# Laravel 5.2 - Odd Results When using Left Join on Subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, left-join, laravel-query-builder

I have the following query:

```
$products = Product::leftJoin(DB::Raw('(SELECT imageable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
                               FROM images WHERE imageable_type = "App\\\Product"
                               GROUP BY imageable_id) AS subquery'), function($join)  {
                                $join->on('subquery.imageable_id', '=', 'products.id');
                        })
                        ->leftJoin('images', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'subquery.imageable_id')
                                ->where('images.created_at', '=', 'subquery.min_created_at');})
                       ->select('products.*', 'images.file_path')
                       ->paginate(5);
```

When I die and dump the query log, the above gets translated as follows:

```
"query" => """
  select `products`.*, `images`.`file_path` from `products`
  left join (SELECT imageable_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
              FROM images WHERE imageable_type = "App\\Product"
              GROUP BY imageable_id) AS subquery on `subquery`.`imageable_id` = `products`.`id` 
  left join `images` on `images`.`imageable_id` = `subquery`.`imageable_id` and `images`.`created_at` = ? 
  limit 5 offset 0
  """
 "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "subquery.min_created_at"

 ]
```

Which looks correct, though I'm unsure why a binding has been added for `subquery.min_created_at`

Now when I execute the above the query in laravel `images`.`file_path` is always null when clearly I know there are related images. When I test the above query by pasting it and running directly in MySQL command line I get the expected results i.e. for products which have images, file_path for image is not null. The only difference when I run in MySQL command line is that I'm not doing any binding for `subquery.min_created_at` - I simply replaced the ? with `subquery.min_created_at`

Any ideas why the query is behaving this way. If I remove the second left join it works correctly but then I can't select the first created image to load e.g doing the following give me the file_path:

```
$products =  Product::leftJoin(DB::Raw('(SELECT imageable_id, file_path
                               FROM images WHERE imageable_type = "App\\\Product"
                               GROUP BY imageable_id) AS subquery'), function($join)  {
                                $join->on('subquery.imageable_id', '=', 'products.id');
                        })
                        ->select('products.*', 'subquery.file_path')
                       ->paginate(5);
```

Ideally I want to get my original query working in - any help appreciated.

Comment: `->where('images.created_at', '=', 'subquery.min_created_at')` - You need to use `DB::raw()` for the second parameter.

Comment: or use `->on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `->where()` for your second join condition:

```
->where('images.created_at', '=', 'subquery.min_created_at')
```

This generates

```
and `images`.`created_at` = ?
```

which the binding is for.

Instead you should use `->on()`;

```
$join->on('images.imageable_id', '=', 'subquery.imageable_id')
     ->on('images.created_at', '=', 'subquery.min_created_at');
```